# Rename Sentry groups table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cartalyst-sentry

The Sentry table which handles all types of accounts is currently called `xx_groups` (`xx` being your prefix). This doesn't seem apt as the word *groups* can be used in every system for something more relevant to the user. The word **roles** seems more ideal. Is there some way to rename it from `xx_groups` to `xx_roles`?

Obviously, the table `xx_users_groups` will also have to be renamed.

Comment: Change `'user_groups_pivot_table' => 'users_groups',` to `'user_groups_pivot_table' => '[desired name]',` in `app/config/packages/cartalyst/sentry/config.php`?

Comment: That's just for the pivot table.